# Which of the following implies $P(S−T)=P(S)−P(T)$ for events $S$ and $T$?

Tags: probability

Which of the following implies $P(S−T)=P(S)−P(T)$ for events $S$ and $T$?

1. $T⊆S$
2. $T⊂S$
3. $S=T$
4. $S⊆T$

I understand that $S-T$ is the difference between the two sets, however, I fail to understand how to decide which implies for this. Sets and subsets are not my strong side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In cases 1), 2) and 3) we have $P(S)=P(T)+P(S-T)$ because $S$ is the disjoint union of $T$and $S-T$. Hence $P(S-T)=P(S)-P(T)$ in these cases. In case 4) this is false. For example if $S$ is the empty set and $T$ is the entire sample space then $P(S)-P(T)=-1$ and $P(S-T)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Remember that $P(\emptyset)=0$ and that for any two events $A$ and $B$, one has $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$.

Comment: I remember this. But I am not sure how that applies here. If $S$ = {1,2} and $T$ = {2,3} then $S-T$ = {1}, how does this link with the probability?

Comment: @LiborZachoval S={1,2} and T={2,3} falls in none of the 4 cases you gave.

Comment: I see... it was an example which confused me

Comment: In such a case the formula above is what helps solve it, but you can't get numerical results because there were no probabilities given. If we assume that the probability space is $\Omega=\{1,2,3\}$ with a uniform probability, i.e, $P(1)=P(2)=P(3)=1/3$, then you know that $P(S\cup T)=1$, $P(S)=P(T)=2/3$ and $P(S\cap T)=1/3$.

Answer (score 1):

You may work backwards using the following fact:

- $S = (S-T) \cup (S\cap T)$ while noting that $(S-T) \cap (S\cap T) = \emptyset$.
- $\Rightarrow P(S) = P(S-T) + P(S\cap T)$

Now, the given condition $P(S−T)=P(S)−P(T)$ is equivalent to 
$$P(S) = P(S−T) + P(T) \stackrel{!}{=} P(S-T) + P(S\cap T) \Leftrightarrow \boxed{P(T) = P(S\cap T)}$$

This condition is satisfied, if 1., 2., 3. holds true.

Concerning 4. just note that $P(T) = P(T-S) + P(S\cap T)$. So, if $S⊂T$ and $P(T-S) > 0$, then the desired condition cannot be satisfied.